# Data URI to JSON in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, json, data-uri

I am facing a problem where my server app gets a JSON's DataURI and I would like to parse it into a JSON again. How could I do this? I tried different things but nothings seems to work. I tried simply parsing it or `encodeURI(data);` but still I can't get the original JSON.

This is the Data URI:
`data:application/json;base64,ew0KICAgICJtYWx0X3R5cGUiOiAibG9nIiwNCiAgICAibWFsdF9kYXRhIjogIldvdywgdSByIGFsbW9zdCB0aGVyZSA6TyINCn0=`

I tried this to encode it too:

```
var data = 'data:application/json;base64,ew0KICAgICJtYWx0X3R5cGUiOiAibG9nIiwNCiAgICAibWFsdF9kYXRhIjogIldvdywgdSByIGFsbW9zdCB0aGVyZSA6TyINCn0=';
Buffer.from(data.toString('utf8'), 'base64').toString('ascii')
```

But I get this if I log it on console: `u+Zje   F- J'm+k0P"&VGEwGR#"&Fvr"@P"&VGEvFF#"%vwrBR"FVw7BFW&R$r P'`

Comment: You should give a context, post some code and explain what you've achieved and what part of code is failing or not giving the expected results. You can't expect to get a full solution here.

Comment: Sorry, I edited my post

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The data URI is JSON encoded in Base64. There are two steps to this:

1. Decode the Base64 (for instance, with the [`atob`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/atob) function), and
2. Parse the resulting JSON

For instance (on a browser):

```js
const dataURI = "data:application/json;base64,ew0KICAgICJtYWx0X3R5cGUiOiAibG9nIiwNCiAgICAibWFsdF9kYXRhIjogIldvdywgdSByIGFsbW9zdCB0aGVyZSA6TyINCn0=";

// 29 = length of "data:application/json;base64,"
const json = atob(dataURI.substring(29));
const result = JSON.parse(json);
console.log(result);
```

Your use of `Buffer` in your question suggests to me that you may be using Node.js. If so, you'd replace the call to `atob` with `Buffer.from(data, 'base64').toString()`:

```
const dataURI = "data:application/json;base64,ew0KICAgICJtYWx0X3R5cGUiOiAibG9nIiwNCiAgICAibWFsdF9kYXRhIjogIldvdywgdSByIGFsbW9zdCB0aGVyZSA6TyINCn0=";

// 29 = length of "data:application/json;base64,"
const json = Buffer.from(dataURI.substring(29), "base64").toString();
const result = JSON.parse(json);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: I am using Node.js, and your code is working for me. Thank you very much

Answer (score 5):

If you don't mind changing the context into an asynchronous one you could use [`fetch()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/fetch) to parse the recourse. `fetch()` is normally used with URLs, but works with data URIs as well (in most browsers).

```js
const dataURI = "data:application/json;base64,ew0KICAgICJtYWx0X3R5cGUiOiAibG9nIiwNCiAgICAibWFsdF9kYXRhIjogIldvdywgdSByIGFsbW9zdCB0aGVyZSA6TyINCn0=";

(async function () {
  const response = await fetch(dataURI);
  const data = await response.json();
  console.log(data);
})();
```

If you are already using a library to simplify network requests, you could use them as well.

Examples:

[jQuery](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/):

```js
const dataURI = "data:application/json;base64,ew0KICAgICJtYWx0X3R5cGUiOiAibG9nIiwNCiAgICAibWFsdF9kYXRhIjogIldvdywgdSByIGFsbW9zdCB0aGVyZSA6TyINCn0=";

(async function() {
  const data = await $.getJSON(dataURI);
  console.log(data);
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

[axios](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios):

```js
const dataURI = "data:application/json;base64,ew0KICAgICJtYWx0X3R5cGUiOiAibG9nIiwNCiAgICAibWFsdF9kYXRhIjogIldvdywgdSByIGFsbW9zdCB0aGVyZSA6TyINCn0=";

(async function() {
  const response = await axios.get(dataURI);
  console.log(response.data);
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/0.21.0/axios.min.js"></script>
```